# setText works differently within different API versions

Tags: android, settext

I downloaded latest android SDK which uses api level 19.

When I use `setText` there is no problem in earlier version of SDK but in the latest version I wrote the same code but when I install the app on my phone it forces to exit. This error occurs when I use `setText()`. However I use the same code earlier version of SDK but there is no error. I couldn't find the issue. Please help.

Here is my code

Activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText("Düğme");
    }
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.yeni.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat output.

Comment: I am sorry but how i can have logcat output?

Answer (score 2):

Your `textView1` is in the fragment layout and not in the activity layout. Activity `onCreate()` is too early to access it with `findViewById()` on the activity view hierarchy.

Move the `findViewById()` and `setText()` to the `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView()` and call `findViewById()` on the inflated `rootView` there, e.g.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText("Düğme");
```

Comment: I am sorry i couldn't understand exactly where i should move. Could you write an example please.  Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Check your logcat: fix the error and then you should do this:

Remove the `Import R` from your activity which can be found at the top of your activity file, and clean + rebuild your solution.

Comment: There is no Import R . My imports:import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;